# Sticky sidebar not scrolling the way it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello everybody and thanks for taking time to read this.

A friend of mine helped me hack together a very basic template with a "sticky" sidebar that is supposed to be max window height and stick on the right side until the footer appears at that point it should scroll upwards like regular content. In my case it appears to "hide" behind the footer element. My javascript/jquery skills are close to null and I have no idea how to fix this. I asked two friends but they could not help me as well.

I uploaded everything to codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGMXOJ.

```
.footer-fix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100vh;
}
```

The .footer-fix class is applied at the moment the sidebar should start scrolling upwards but it fails todo so.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Since you have a fixed height of `100vh` on the sidebar, you should make sure its `.main-content` counterpart has a `min-height` of at least that.  This way you don't have freaky behavior when you remove the sidebar from the normal flow of the DOM (when you add `position: fixed`).  So:

```
.main-content {
    ...
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

2) You're using floats.  Always, always [clear floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).  This is as simple as adding an `:after` pseudo-element to `.content`:

```
.content:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

This prevents the parent of the floated elements from collapsing, allowing you to size/position the children relative to the parent.  You'll need this for step 4.

3) Just a setup change:  Move the `.footer` outside the `main` tag, so instead of this structure:

```
<main>
    ...
    <aside>...</aside>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</main>
```

You have this:

```
<main>
    ...
    <aside>...</aside>
</main>
<footer>...</footer>
```

(I'd also use the HTML5 `footer` tag and change the CSS selectors).  This makes the next step possible:

4) Change the CSS of `.footer-fix` to:

```
.footer-fix {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

So when you're ready to unfix the sidebar, you'll absolutely position it at the bottom of its parent.  To make this work, you'll also need to create a stacking context for the parent (`.content`):

```
.content {
    ...
    position: relative; /* defines a new stacking context */
}
```

5) And finally, your JavaScript will look like this:

```
var $wannaBeSticky = $('.sidebar'),
    currentPosition = $wannaBeSticky.offset().top,
    footerOffset = $('footer').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop >= currentPosition) {
        $wannaBeSticky.addClass('fix');
    } else {
        $wannaBeSticky.removeClass('fix');
    }

    if (scrollTop + $(this).height() >= footerOffset) {
        $wannaBeSticky.removeClass('fix').addClass('footer-fix');
    } else {
        $wannaBeSticky.removeClass('footer-fix');
    }
});
```

This is very similar to what you had before, I just cleaned up the code and improved the logic for adding/removing the classes.

You may also want to handle window resizing and trigger a scroll on `window` on page load.

Here's a working [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/bowheart/pen/QyaKwO).  Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Iam having a look at it now to see and learn from the differences.

Comment: Hey Josh I have been trying to fix a bug I found the past few hours I started working with this and I can not get it to work for Internet Explorer the way it should. Whenever the footer appears the whole sidebar disappears. Could you maybe point me towards the right direction in fixing this please?